# EC2 instance running apache tomcat port 8443 not accessible

Tags: amazon-ec2, amazon-web-services, tomcat7

I have a AWS EC2 ubuntu 14.04 machine and apache tomcat 7 is installed on that machine.
I deployed a web application on apache tomcat7 and started the server, I had an issue where EC2 machine running apache tomcat7 was not accessible from outside using the port 8080.
Then I figured that we have to [EC2 instance running apache tomcat not accessible from outside](https://serverfault.com/questions/666338/ec2-instance-running-apache-tomcat-not-accessible-from-outside/731513#731513) do this that is present in the link, then port 8080 worked.

Now the issue is SSL port 8443 does not work, if I hit my web application in this manner https://{ipaddress}:8443.

Note - I have generated a certificate using java keytool and configured in the Tomcat server.xml

```
<Connector port="8443" protocol="org.apache.coyote.http11.Http11NioProtocol" SSLEnabled="true"
           maxThreads="150" scheme="https" secure="true"
           clientAuth="false" sslProtocol="TLS" keystoreFile="/home/ubuntu/mycert.crt"
           keystorepass="*****" keyAlias="tomcat" />
```

And my EC2 Security Groups Inbound Configurations
[image]

Can someone let me know what Im doing wrong?

Comment: Are you sure it's actually listening on port 8443? Post the output of "netstat -tunlp | grep 8443".

Comment: @EEAA Output  - 
 tcp6       0      0 :::8443                 :::*                    LISTEN      14765/java

Answer (score 0, accepted):

After looking into the Catalina.out log, I found the issue i.e. In the I mentioned above, tomcat7 has the property named as "keystorePass" (P is capital in keystorePass) but in tomcat6 "keystorepass" also works. Due to this issue, password was not getting rightly set.